# RemoteViews to LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: java, android-studio

LocalBroadcastManager does not receive broadcast intent from RemoteViews PendingIntent.

So if it is true then is there any idea or way out to do communicate in between RemoteViews and LocalBroadcastManager?

I am using RemoteViews for Notification custom view, which run within a foreground service.
And when click on button within RemoteViews, it will call a method within service.

```
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom);
Intent intent1 = new Intent("myintent");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button,pi);
```

But LocalBroadcastManager does not receive this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i kinda sort out this.
Using another BroadcastReceiver as middle man to receive broadcast for PendingIntent and sendbroadcast through LocalBroadcastManager which can receive by service's LBM